# Is there any way to get the embedded terminal gedit plugin in the mac version?

Tags: macos, gedit

I downloaded gedit for mac and it seems like there is no embedded terminal plugin in the plugin selection preferences.

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: I'm also interested if there is similar functionality (that exists on the Linux side now), for **Mac OS X, with gedit**.  In particular, Ruby, Python, and/or debugger support--all of which would require a gedit-gmate like plugin (currently on Linux), which I presume is what Danish94 is asking about here.  Thanks!